# How to change the Visual studio target path?

Tags: c#-4.0

Unfortunately, I have copied and pasted one Program(Project) to a path. This project has been developed in Visual studio 2010. Now, this project is not executing. It prompts the target path. How can we change this target path?

Comment: Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug target 'F:\sample\DatabaseTool\WPSDatabaseTool\bin\DataTool.exe' is missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to point at the correct location for the target assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can open `*.csproject` file with any text or XML editor, change the wrong path, then save the file. Then re-open the project with Visual Studio again.

Comment: I have changed  the .csproject at this place <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>. But this project refers the path 'obj\x86\debug'. How to change this ?

Comment: I would do search (and replace) in your `*.csproject` file. I think you have multiple entries for output path, based on debug|release|CPU type configuration.